# Temporary failure in name resolution error

Tags: networking, kali-linux, networkmanager

I am trying to connect to the internet, but am facing issues with configuring my network to get rid of an error saying "Temporary failure in name resolution".
I am using a hyper-v VM for Kali Linux.
My resolv.conf file has 8.8.8.8

[image]

[image]

`192.168.0.208` is the ip I see when I run `ipconfig` on Windows 11 powershell, where the VM is being run.
[image]
*This is the output from running* `ipconfig`

[image]
*I can successfully ping* `192.168.0.208`

I can't ping 8.8.8.8:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 pint statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 0 received, +11 errors, 100% packet loss, time 16285ms
```

From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.208 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: What is `192.168.0.1`? Is it connected to the internet? From it, can it ping `8.8.8.8`? Is `NAT` enabled on it? You are not running DHCP, so can you at least ping `192.168.0.1`?

Comment: @Bib `192.168.0.1` is my ip that I see from running `ipconfig` on Windows 11 powershell, where I am running the VM. I am able to ping it with no issues.

https://prnt.sc/26x954d
https://prnt.sc/26x98h7

Comment: That is an ip address which you gave. If you bothered to look just above it, you will see the statement `media disconnected`. Meaning, you have not setup the network correctly in the hyper-v host. You need to set it to an `external network`. Then get rid of the manual IP address and set it to be dhcp sourced. And edit your question and tell us what the IP address is of your internet connected router.

Comment: Please do NOT post images. Pinging `192.168.0.208` means nothing, it is the localhost. What on earth is on `172.16.32.X`? What is the IP address of your internet connected router?

Comment: @Bib Sorry, I'm quite new to this and am unsure about the technicals of this stuff. Thanks for the help. Which images should I not post, and I thought the ip address of my connected router was in the `ipconfig` command?

Comment: Last time, what is the IP address of your internet conencted router? The (I assume) wifi router that is connected through to Virgin Media. As for images, do not post ANY where plain text will do.

Comment: @Bib Thank you for your patience, my router's ip is `192.168.0.208`
And yes, you are right that it is a Virgin Media router. I looked up how to find my router ip and got it from my network settings on windows where it says the IPv4 address.

Comment: I am lost. `172.31.32.1` is listed as the hyper-v hosts IP address. I want to know what the IP address is of the wifi router which I think is `192.168.0.1`. Anyway, shutdown kali, within the hyper-v host, reconfigure the kali client network for `external network`, start kali, then within kali, tell it to use dhcp. Anyway, I'm heading for my kip.

Comment: Kali linux is not intended to be a beginner's operating system

Comment: @Bib got it! If you write a quick answer to this I'm happy to mark it as the solution. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @symcbean the problem is not really with Kali, it's the hyper-v network setup that is confusing things. Would have happened regardless of the client o/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup within the hyper-v host has been set for internal networks, so:

> 1. Shutdown Kali
> 2. Enter hyper-v config for Kali
> 3. Set network type to `external network`
> 4. Start Kali
> 5. Set Kali network to be automatic/dhcp

Answer (score 0):

"Temporary failure in name resolution" error may be a firewall blocking one or both of the following ports:

port 43, used for whois lookup
port 53, used for domain name resolution
Open the ports in UFW Firewall
Type the following command to allow traffic on port 43 using UFW firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 43/tcp
```

UFW confirms the rule is successfully updated.

Allowing port 43 in UFW.
Repeat the command for port 53.

```
sudo ufw allow 53/tcp
```

Reload UFW with the following command:

```
sudo ufw reload
```

The output confirms the operation was successful.

Reloading UFW firewall.
Open the ports in firewalld
Some Linux distributions such as CentOS use firewalld as their default firewall. The syntax to open port 43 in firewalld is:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=43/tcp --permanent
```

firewalld outputs the word success.

Allowing port 43 in firewalld.
Repeat the command for port 53.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=53/tcp --permanent
```

Reload the firewall.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both of these commands fail for me though: https://prnt.sc/26x7e45

Comment: At this point, he has no need for port 43 to be open.

Comment: DNS needs port 53/UDP and 53/TCP ; not 43